# How to import module present in parent directory to sub directory modules

Tags: python-3.x

I have  my folder structure as below:

```
XYZ
  - abc.py
  - /123
    - mn.py
```

XYZ is the parent directory, which is having file abc.py and sub-directory /123. Further this sub-directory contains mn.py file. Now i need to import abc in mn. How can I achieve this. Can someone please give some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in sys module to add your package.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")

# Rest of your code here.
```

In your case you could simply insert the path as below.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "..")

# Rest of your code here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Import paths are always relative to the directory from which the Python interpreter runs. If you're running the Python interpreter from the `XYZ` directory, you can simply do:

```
import abc
```

in `mn.py`, since `abc.py` is located at the source root.